# Libreoffice Writer - append continuous numbers before line (character)

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Let's say I got this text:

> Line 1
> # Line 2
> # Line 3
> Line 4
> # Line 5
> Line 6
> # Line 7

and I want to append continuous numbers before every line that start with `#`, so I want to get this:

> Line 1
> **1**
> # Line 2
> **2**
> # Line 3
> Line 4
> **3**
> # Line 5
> Line 6
> **4**
> # Line 7

How can I do that? With `Find & Replace`? But, I am not sure how can I put continuous numbers in `replace` field...